# How to change your keyboard key of square brackets to parentheses in DrRacket?

Tags: settings, racket

The square brackets are next to the button 'P' and before 'Enter'. So I want to change them so that I can use them as parentheses instead of square brackets. 
It is easier to type that way.

I  also found the answer but let the people know in advance.

**Preferences**  ->  **Editing** -> **Scheme** or **Racket** -> (check) **Automatically adjust opening square brackets.**

Comment: Edited to "DrRacket" since this is about the DrRacket specifically.  In any case, if you know the answer, then where is the question that you expect people to answer?

Comment: @yarian: you are correct; however, there is convention for when you should use which. If the set DrRacket to automatically adjust opening square brackets in the way that the OP posted, it will always put the correct one if you push the `[` button, as well as match closing braces properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe you can configure Dr. Racket to this. Try changing it for your specific operating system.

On the other hand, the Racket reader does not differentiate between square brackets, parentheses, and curly braces. However, it is considered common practice to differentiate them while you're writing code. For instance, the proper way to write a variable assignment is:

```
(let ([var1 value1] 
      [var2 value2]) 
   body)
```

In particular, there are a number of extra Dr. Racket key-bindings which exist to make your life as a programmer easier. Try, for instance hitting Alt+(, really, Meta+(, or the sequence "ESC; (", and you will get a balanced set of parentheses with the cursor placed inside. Same thing goes for brackets and curly braces.

For a list of all such bindings, go to Edit -> Keybindings -> Show Active Keybindings.

Comment: It can be done in the way that the OP put into the text of his question.